# javascript div onclick if else control

Tags: javascript

First of all, my English is very bad, sorry for that.
I don't know much javascript and I would like your help.

there is one div

```
    <div id="click"></div>
```

when clicking on this div

```
if (...click){
var a = "click open";
}else{
var a = "";
}
```

I need a coding like this. When clicked, the variable a should be filled and empty when not clicked.
how do i do this please help
all i want is when it is clicked the variable a will be full when not clicked it will still work but it will be empty

```
if (...click){
var a = "click open";
}else{
var a = "";
}
```

all i want is when it is clicked the variable a will be full when not clicked it will still work but it will be empty

Answer (score 1):

Considering the following html :

```
<div id="click"></div>
```

You can initialize the variable in javascript as an empty string and add an event listener to change the value when the div is clicked with the following js code:

```
let a = "";
const click = document.getElementById("click");

click.addEventListener('click', function(){

    a = "click open";

  })
```

Comment: thanks for your answer the a="" loop is working on any click a="click" is not working

Comment: which loop are you talking about?

Comment: alert(a); when i do it just a=""; when i click i get a = "click open"; not working

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question, because your button is empty here. So, if your button is empty, how do you click on the button and get the result? That is why I added two answers and hope it will help you.

```js
//example one
const clickBtn = document.getElementById("click");
let click = true;
if (click) {
  var a = "click open";
  clickBtn.innerHTML = a;
} else {
  var a = "";
  clickBtn.innerHTML = a;
}

//exmaple two 
const clickBtn2 = document.getElementById("click2");
let click2 = true;
clickBtn2.addEventListener("click", () => {
if (click2) {
  var a = "yes, click open";
  clickBtn2.innerHTML = a;
} else {
  var a = "";
  clickBtn2.innerHTML = a;
}
});
```

```html
<div id="click"></div>
<div id="click2">Click me</div>
```

Comment: thank you, your examples are very good, I get value when clicked, but no value when not clicked

Comment: this is what i wanted to do i didn't know how to do it`   let jmin = "";
   const click = document.getElementById("price_range");
   click.addEventListener('click', function(){
   var jmin = "min=" + minimum_price;
   })
   history.pushState(null, '', 'index.php?' + kategori + filtb + filtr + filts + jmin);`

Answer (score 0):

I added the text "Click" to give the element a clickable area.

```js
let a = '';

document
  .querySelector('#click')
  .addEventListener('click', () => a = 'clicked');
```

```html
<div id="click">Click</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I wanted to do I didn't know how to do it?

```
let jmin = "";
const click = document.getElementById("price_range");
click.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var jmin = "min=" + minimum_price;
})
history.pushState(null, '', 'index.php?' + kategori + filtb + filtr + filts + jmin);
```